# Avoid toll roads feature weights values explanation

Tags: javascript, here-api, here-maps-rest

Quick question in the tollroad feature weight:
Shouldn't a value -1 (tollroad: -1) return a route even if it can't avoid toll roads?
& what is the difference between -1 & -2 feature weights for the tollroad feature?

here is the link for the docs where this part is not clear for me: https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-param-type-routing-mode.html#resource-param-type-routing-mode__type-route-feature

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a routing call from point A to B, the response is several routes between the places arranged by either distance/time taken.

If the value of the parameter tollroad is set to -1, it will return all possible routes. The roads with a toll will be ranked lower and will appear lower in the list of routes available.

If the parameter is set to -2, the router will avoid roads with a toll. If there is no such road available, only then, will it return a road with a toll.

If the parameter is set to -3, roads with a toll booth will be completely avoided. If there is no such route available, no route will be returned.

Hope this helps!